# If I set an image width to 15% how does that change the original size (height and width) in pixels?

Tags: css

When I resize an image to using just "width: 15%" both the width and height of the image change so it's just displayed smaller. But how does this change the original dimensions in pixels. What would be the new height and width in pixels?

Comment: Your original image will not be affected. Not sure what exactly you are asking.

Comment: If you can show us some code of your css and html would better? Are you working locally or can you share a link?

Comment: Well, the new width would be 15% of the original... Why don't you just try it and see? With the code in place, right click the image and select Inspect Element. Your browser's developer tools should be able to tell you the computed height and width.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, it depends on the dimensions of the containing block. If your elements aren't inside anything else like a div, then this depend on your viewport

If your browser is 1000 px wide and you show something as `width: 15%` that isn't inside any other element, it will show as 150 pixels.

That said, the original dimensions of your image will not change. The only thing that will change is how it is displayed.

Comment: Actually, it depends on the dimensions of the containing block, not the viewport.